# How do I launch an Excel document in Windows, edit it and get the application to ask to save it?

Tags: windows, vb.net

I can launch Excel with the document I want using VB.Net 2010:

```
Dim p As New System.Diagnostics.Process  
p.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\temp\myfile.xlsx"  
p.Start()
```

Excel starts OK with the file opened. I edit the file, but when I close it down, Excel doesn't ask if I want to save changes. So it closes and loses my edits.

If I do the same with a text file:

```
Dim p As New System.Diagnostics.Process  
p.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\temp\myfile.txt"  
p.Start()
```

It opens (in Notepad++), I edit it and close it, and Notepad++ asks if I want to save changes. Great!

I've now tried similar code with a Word document - and that's OK. Also with an OpenOffice Sheet document and that works as well.

This behaviour is happening in Windows 7 with Excel 2010. It works as expected in Windows XP with Excel 2007.

What am I doing wrong with Excel? Is it me?

Comment: There shouldn't be anything with your VB.net code involved. Is the file read-only perhaps?

Comment: Hi Andrew, the file isn't read-only. Works fine when I launch it via Windows Explorer.

Comment: Silly question; is c:\temp\ really the location of the file? Totally wild and silly guess if so; maybe Excel thinks it's not supposed to save a file in such a location? (like I said, totally wild guess...)

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your persistence. The actual location is: 'C:\Users\David\Desktop\Customers'. But when I try the code with a text file, it does ask to save after an edit. I'll try it with other files to see if I need to point the finger at Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it's not related to the way I was opening the document (using System.Diagnosis.Process). I initially thought it was. If I open files via Explorer, edit them and close Excel, it doesn't ask to save the changed file. So it's not a programming issue.

Thanks for the help anyway guys.
Dave

Comment: OK, found out why this happened. It was my fault. I'd used 'Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False' and not switched it back to true. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't recreate your error. I ran the app with and without Excel already being open. I closed out of Excel and then by just closing the workbook only. I was prompted to save each time.

You may need to check your settings in Excel. Could be a security setting. Are you doing any other changes to the excel file programatically or are they just manual changes through the Excel UI only?

Maybe SuperUser.com can help.

Comment: Hi Jeff. I've just tried the same app on Windows XP and Excel 2007, and this works as expected. However, this behaviour I've described is on Windows 7 and with Excel 2010. This is a weird one.

Comment: I was using Windows XP and Excell 2007 as well.

Comment: Thanks for the input Jeff. By the way, the file isn't changed programatically, I just want to run Excel with a specified file. It seems as though Excel is not performing correctly when I launch it with this code. I wondered if there was another way to launch Excel without using System.Diagnosis.Process ?